# Why is this code causing an endless loop?

Tags: bash

I have one script calling another. Problem is that is running endless.
Please help.

script1: /tmp/caseCheck

```
#!/bin/sh
aaa=1
echo "Begin $1" 
case "$1" in
 start)
    echo "Start"    
    ;;
 stop)
    echo "Stop"
    ;;
 reload)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
 *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|reload}"
    ;;
esac
```

script2: /tmp/trigger

```
#!/bin/bash

do_admin() {
    echo "Starting Trigger"
}

do_admin

. /tmp/caseCheck "reload"
echo "-----------------------"

exit 0
```

When I run ./trigger the expected result is:

Starting Trigger

Begin reload

Begin stop

Stop

Begin start

Start

'----------------'

but it keeps going and going...

Producing the following output

Starting Trigger
Begin reload
Starting Trigger
Begin reload
Starting Trigger
Begin reload
Starting Trigger
Begin reload
Starting Trigger
Begin reload
Starting Trigger
Begin reload

...

Please help

Comment: it's a switch and you could use break after stop if you don't want to start after the stop, you could inverse start and stop.

Comment: @headmax bash `case` does not fall through. OP, we need more output and code. the piece you pasted should terminate.

Comment: It still runs endless with breaks after every case?

Comment: correction: in fact bash extension allows fall through but it's not the case here.

Comment: That is all the code. Only the two scripts. Nothing else.

Comment: aha. `. /tmp/caseCheck "reload"` don't do this. just do `/tmp/caseCheck "reload"`. i will explain.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It works great now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
. /tmp/caseCheck "reload"
```

is the problem here. Basically you are sourcing `/tmp/caseCheck` into your `/tmp/trigger` and set `reload` into your argument. After sourcing it, `$0` remains trigger. Removing the dot should fix it.